# Apache 2.4.20 and "SeverTokens Prod" causes "segmentation fault"

Tags: centos, security, apache-2.4

Simply stated I am running Apache 2.4.20 on CentOs 6 and am in the process of hardening this VM prior to rolling it out.  I added this line:

```
ServerTokens ProductOnly
```

Which on restart promptly gave me this response:

```
sudo service httpd start
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl: line 79:  7073 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $HTTPD -k $ARGV
```

I am by no means an operations or linux type - just trying to plug holes, while my organization grows.  I tried the other possible values there such as Major which works fine:

```
curl -I localhost
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 08 Jun 2016 13:28:37 GMT
Server: Apache/2
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload
Last-Modified: Mon, 11 Jun 2007 18:53:14 GMT
ETag: "2d-432a5e4a73a80"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 45
Content-Type: text/html
```

Any help on proceeding on to finding more information, or how i may resolve this is appreciated  -thanks

Comment: Does the abbreviated [`ServerTokens Prod`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servertokens) instead of `ProductOnly` work?

Comment: No - unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you are not using mod_security or any module that may tap in the response headers (not including mod_headers which can't touch that header).

Also make sure the installation path is correct and you are not mixing different version installations.

I am using 2.4.20 as you with ServerTokens Prod in dozens of server and I don't get a segfault.